# How to combine characters to create icons in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, icons, fxml

In Windows you can combine characters to build your icons:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font#layering-and-mirroring

[image]

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in Javafx to create an icon for a Javafx Button?

(Preferably in FXML)

**Edit:**
Here's how I'm currently adding the button in FXML:

```
<Button text="&#xE700;">
  <font>
    <Font name="Segoe MDL2 Assets" size="14.0" />
  </font>
</Button>
```

**Answer:**

With help of the answer below I used this FXML:

```
<Button>
    <graphic>
        <StackPane style="-fx-background-color: transparent;">
            <Label text="A" />
            <Label text="B" />
        </StackPane>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

Comment: A `StackPane`, maybe? You'll need to be much more specific about your needs and implementation in order to get a real answer.

Comment: I need this on a Button. I don't think StackPane is the proper way.

Comment: Why would it not be the proper way? You can add a `StackPane` to a Button just fine.

Comment: Zephyr is refering to the use for te `Button.graphic` property. The `Button.text` property does not provide functionality for placing characters on top of each other. It's unclear in the question how you're integrating these symbols in the button though.

Comment: I updated my question to include how I'm currently doing this. What would be the FXML notation for embedding two characters using StackPane in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate it I use these two images:

[image]               [image]

To construct a button that looks like:

[image]

Stack the images and use as button's graphic node:

```
private static final String[] images = {
        "https://i.imgur.com/g52UeNO.png",
        "https://i.imgur.com/kvHOLJ4.jpg",
};

ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(images[0]);
ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(images[1]);
StackPane sp = new StackPane(imageView1, imageView2);
Button button = new Button("", sp);
```

**Edit**: to stack chars use :

```
Text t1 = new Text(Character.toString('O'));
t1.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", 20));
t1.setFill(Color.RED);
Text t2 = new Text(Character.toString('x'));
t2.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", 12));
t1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
StackPane sp = new StackPane(t1, t2);
Button button = new Button("", sp);
```

Comment: But this is an image. What about combining unicode characters? Also, how would you do this in FXML?

Comment: He's using a specific font (Segoe MDL2 Assets), not images, and wants to layer those glyphs. My work machine does not have that font installed or JavaFX doesn't seem to support it out-of-the-box.

Comment: In my question I use Segoe MDL2 Assets font, but you can use any font you like. If it works with one font it should work with any font. So even if you could do it with Arial font please let me know how.